# UIViewController - alloc and init vs. instantiate?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

What is the difference between the following two ways of instantiating view controllers?

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
// present vc...
```

vs.

```
[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewControllerScene"]
```

It seems that `alloc init` can magically identify the proper scene in the storyboard; how does this happen? Is it invoking `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` under the hood? Which is the preferred way of instantiating a view controller? Will the first way result in memory leak or extraneous view controller instances?

Comment: How did you test this?  My tests do not show alloc init instantiating from the storyboard.

Comment: I used the first method to push in a new view controller and it worked.

Comment: What's the down vote about?

Comment: I see from your accepted answer comments that your test was faulty.  Makes sense.  (FWIW I did not downvote the question and in fact I think it was a perfectly good one given what you thought you experienced.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[[MyObject alloc] init]` creates a new object. It's *not* retrieving an object from a Storyboard, just allocating memory for it and instantiating it.

`instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:` creates a new view controller (if the identifier exists in the storyboard) and configures it according to how the view controller was configured object in the Storyboard file.

Both cases will create a new instance for each call.

---

If you have configured a view controller in the Storyboard (for example connected outlets, actions, etc.) and you want to retrieve it, you should read it from the Storyboard. If you would create a new instance (not from the Storyboard) it would not have this configuration.

Comment: I see. You are right the first method does not configure any IBOutlets I set in Interface Builder. Because in my case it is a Table View Controller so I overlooked the IBOutlet differences.

Answer (score 0):

`[[MyViewController alloc]init]` will instantiate a new instance of a MyViewController but it will not be associated with a view or any other elements from the storyboard - that is any properties which are set via `IBOutlet`s will be nil. You could use this statement if you are populating all of your UI programatically in the view controller.

```
[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewControllerScene"]
```

On the other hand, locates the scene in the storyboard with the specified identifier, instantiates a new instance of the view controller specified in that scene's custom class and connects all of the outlets (such as the view outlet).